# How to shift cache / session data of one server to another?

Tags: java, session, caching, copy

I have two servers one with lot of cached data and session data (coming from a database, and changes made on this) on it. I want to securely maintain that data on secondary server. That is required to serve client efficiently in case of failure of primary server.

Options we tried are:

1. Caching data on secondary server also and updating every time changes made on primary.
   But this is not feasible as primary server is handling lot requests (around 10 requests/ second). Memory issues will come.
2. Removing cache completely also causes speed issues (due to calling the database every time)

Please provide me another way which will effectively solve the problem.

Its database over hibernate. And by direct querying we are loading IP'S of client into an hash map from database. Hope this clears my point. On fail over I require all hash map current values on secondary server.

Comment: can you give more details, cache usually depends on the technology. Data base over Hibernate, JPA, direct JDBC?

Comment: Its database over hibernate. And by direct quering we are loading IPS of client into an hash map from database. Hope this clears my point. On failover I require all hashmap current values on secondary server.